# Active Admin works locally but not on heroku when I push to heroku

Tags: git, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

Active Admin works locally but not on heroku when I pushed to heroku.
I'm running on rails 4. 
The font of the Active Admin and everything works fine locally but when I pushed to heroku, the font is all over the place, it became basic html with no css....etc.
What's going on?

The command I used are, 
1. git add .
2. git commit -am
3. git push heroku master

Comment: are there any errors from heroku in the output you get when pushing to heroku? do you see any errors in your heroku logs when you're accessing the app? it sounds like your assets might not be getting compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.

By default, Rails 4 prevents the public folder from being visible, which is where precompiled assets live by default. Try adding the following to your Gemfile:

gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production

Source: Rails 4 on Heroku